# Что делать, если нужно работать с двумя контейнерами frame layout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, bottom-navigation-view

У меня есть activity main c bottom navigation и 3 фрагментами. В первом фрагменте есть recycler view со списоком, при нажатии на элементы которого должен открываться новый фрагмент. Однако в этом фрагменте не должен быть bottom navigation - получается, что в activity main надо создать два контейнера - один для фрагментов bottom navigation, другой для фрагментов recycler view. Можно ли так сделать? Или есть более простой способ?

Comment: А не лучше ли размещать их в одном контейнере, но у разметок фрагментов `bottomNavigation` будет `margin` снизу?

Answer (score 1):

Я предложил бы вам `bottom_navigation + ViewPager` для переключения между фрагментами перенести из `main_activity_layout` в новый фрагмент, и вот его уже показывать в mainActivity. тогда, в случае перехода к фрагменту без bottom_navigation, вы просто заменете фрагмент вставленный в главный Frame.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, схемотичный рисунок вам поможет понять мои объяснения)) Удачи.